# Ruby on Rails and Oracle cursor. How to open cursor inside cursor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, fetch

So i do have cursor witch i'm calling from PLSQL.

```
plsql.get_values(code, id) do |cursor|
  if cursor[:p_error].blank?
    outcome += cursor[:p_bui_data].fetch_all
  else
    outcome = cursor[:p_error]
  end
```

This script give me the this output

```
[["1513131313153131", 0, 1220, "Text 1", "Text 2", 0, "3270900", #<PLSQL::OCIConnection::Cursor:0x13514568 @raw_cursor=#<OCI8::Cursor:0x135148f8>, @connection=#<PLSQL::OCIConnection:0x1054ce48 @raw_connection=nil, @activerecord_class=ActiveRecord::Base, @raw_driver=:oci>>]]
```

So as you see inside it there is still cursor. The question is how to fetch it?

So the final output that i wanna see is like

```
[["1513131313153131", 0, 1220, "Text 1", "Text 2", 0, "3270900", "11111111"]]
```

Where `11111111` is fetched cursor value.

Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Maybe call [.raw_cursor](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-plsql/0.5.3/PLSQL%2FOCIConnection%2FCursor:raw_cursor) on the cursor object?

Comment: @maxpleaner Thank you for your answer, but if i apply it on a page for cursor i get this output `#<OCI8::Cursor:0x136cb768>`

Comment: Well, maybe you can find something in the documentation: [OC18::Cursor](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/OCI8/Cursor)